# Is it possible to split this up into multiple methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I was working on an array program where the program would accept 10 numbers and output them in ascending order. The code itself works fine, but I was wondering if I could get help with splitting the code into 2 different methods. (eg: sorting as a separate method)

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class arrayProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double count;
        count = 10;
        double temp;


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            double num[] = new double[(int) count];
            System.out.println("Enter array elements:");
            for (double i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                num[(int) i] = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            scan.close();
            for (double i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                for (double j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
                    if (num[(int) i] > num[(int) j]) {
                        temp = num[(int) i];
                        num[(int) i] = num[(int) j];
                        num[(int) j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Array Elements in Ascending Order: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(num[i] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.print(num[(int) (count - 1)]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A different question: why are you using `double`s as indexes for loops?

Comment: so that i would be able to input decimals as elements

Comment: After a quick read, you can split it into 3 methods: one to read the array, one to sort it, and one to print it out.

Comment: @Qurthala FYI, that's not needed (in fact it doesn't work, and that's why you need to  cast them so you can use them as array indexes). The important thing is that `num` is declared as an array of `double`s, but array indexes are **always** (non-negative) `int`s

Comment: Always use ints to index arrays regardless of the array type.    The index and the type of array (double, long, Object, etc) are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to split this up into multiple methods. And you should.

Think about the various tasks being accomplished by your app. Think about responsibilities, think about jobs to be performed. And think about data to be kept and managed. Then think about naming — naming that fits well helps to clarify one’s thinking.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028004/is-it-possible-to-split-this-up-into-multiple-methods/73029499#comment128981831_73028004) by Kuhn, I too see three jobs here:

- Gathering input from a user
- Tracking that input, and sorting the data.
- Reporting that data.

With that in mind, I wrote this example class.

```java
package work.basil.example.num;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoublesMachine
{
    private final int limit = 3;  // Or 10 as in Question, whatever.
    private double[] doubles;

    public DoublesMachine ( ) { doubles = new double[ limit ]; }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        this.gather();
        this.sort();
        this.report();
    }

    // Use console to gather inputs for a series of double primitive values, collected inta an array.
    private void gather ( )
    {
        try (
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
        )
        {
            System.out.println( "Tracking " + this.limit + " numbers." );
            int index = 0;
            do
            {
                int ordinal = index + 1;
                System.out.println( "Enter number # " + ordinal + " of " + this.limit + ": " );
                double input = scanner.nextDouble();
                this.doubles[ index ] = input;
                index = index + 1;  // Increment.
            } while ( ( index + 1 ) <= this.limit );
        }
    }

    private void sort ( )
    {
        Arrays.sort( this.doubles );
    }

    private void report ( )
    {
        String output = Arrays.toString( this.doubles );
        System.out.println( "output = " + output );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        DoublesMachine app = new DoublesMachine();
        app.demo();
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Tracking 3 numbers.
Enter number # 1 of 3: 
2.2
Enter number # 2 of 3: 
1.1
Enter number # 3 of 3: 
3.3
output = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
```

Notice that we moved virtually all the code outside of the `main` method. The `main` method is *not* [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). It is basically a hack, a necessary evil, to jump-start the execution of your app. Try to minimize code there, and start using objects as soon as possible.

As explained in the comments, always use an integer as the counter of your `for` loop, not a floating-point type like `double`.

Notice how we placed the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) instantiation within [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. This ensures a [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html) resource such as `Scanner` is automatically closed even if an exception is thrown.

---

For learning purposes, I suggest you give the above example only a quick glance. Get the general idea, then try writing your own. The learning is in the doing.

By the way, in real work, we would write separate classes. This gives more flexibility, and allows for writing tests. For example, gathering input from a user should be entirely separate from the management of state (the collection of `double` numbers), in a class of its own. But that is beyond the scope of a Java 101 student assignment.